# how to update seekbar using a edittext

Tags: java, android

i read an example of how to show the progres of a seekbar to the edittext this is the web page:

[Simple Seekbar In Android](http://androidprogramz.blogspot.mx/2012/07/simple-seekbar-in-android.html)

now my problem is how to change the seekbar if i introduce a number inside the edittext box? thanks for any help

if you can acces the web page i will also post the code:

main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and the java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;


public class SeekbarActivity extends Activity 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SeekBar sb=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    final EditText et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser)
        {
        //---change the font size of the EditText---

        et.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }
        });

       }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)

A quick example :

```
//et and sk are class variables
et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
sk = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try{
            //Update Seekbar value after entering a number
            sk.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
});
```

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802397/change-seekbar-progress-based-on-edittext-value