# Change SeekBar progress based on EditText value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, seekbar

I am trying to change the progress of a `SeekBar` based on the number entered in an `EditText` but for some reason the `EditText` value goes to the max and I can't slide the thumb in the `SeekBar`.

What I am looking to achieve: If the value entered in the `EditText` anywhere between 70 and 190 (including both number) change the progress of the `SeekBar` to that value.

Partial Java code:

```
etOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSyst);
        etOne.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String filtered_str = s.toString();
                if (Integer.parseInt(filtered_str) >= 70 && Integer.parseInt(filtered_str) <= 190) {
                    sbSyst.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(filtered_str));
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        });
```

The partial XML:

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/syst_bar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:progress="0"
            android:max="120"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_state" />
```

I add 70 to each value, because `SeekBar` starts at 0, but I want it to start at 70.

After using the above code, this is what it looks like:

[image]

The `SeekBar` is at the maximum number and the `EditText` is at the maximum as well.

Comment: post the xml layout that you use for the seekbar

Comment: Added an update to my question with the XML

Comment: seekbar max value is 120: android:max="120"

Comment: Yes because in my code I add 70. Technically I need it to be from 70 to 190, which is 0 to 120.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
etOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSyst);
        etOne.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                if (i >= 70 && i <= 190) {
                    sbSyst.setProgress( i - 70); // This ensures 0-120 value for seekbar
                }
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        });
```