# Change the SeekBar status with EditText and viceversa with 2 decimal space

Tags: java, android, kotlin, decimal, seekbar

I could not find this use case where the seekBar has decimal value.
I need a seekBar that ranges from 20,00 to 100000,00
**

> First case:

**
When the user scroll the seekBar it needs to reflect the progress to the Edittext
**

> Second case:

**
When the user inputs a number ex(123,50) it has to reflect this value to the seekBar

Comment: Please refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349747/6076979

Comment: But it doesnt work with decimals, only Int numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can try multiplying float values with 100